# 301 redirect in htaccess for URL with ?lt parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to put 301 redirect in htaccess for http://www.price4india.co.in/?lt which shall redirect it to home page i.e. http://www.price4india.co.in/
I am able to use the following code successfully but it creates another problem as the admin page (Wordpress site) after login doesn't open properly.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lt [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

The best option would be that the redirect shall be applicable for only this URL.

Can anyone please suggest me way around for this.

Thanx in advance,

Jai

Comment: `RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]` - match on a completely empty (relative) path only, then this will only apply to the root URL.

Comment: @Broe thnx a ton, it works perfectly fine. have a grt day. best rgds

Comment: You wrote: "the redirect shall be applicable for only this URL". My question: for _which_ URL?